# TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable when calculating dot product of vectors

Tags: python, vector, typeerror, dot-product

I am new to Python and trying to execute dot product of 2 vectors using zip.

```
from typing import List    
vector = List[float]    
def dot_prod(v:vector,w:vector) -> float:    
    return sum(v_i*w_i for v_i,w_i in zip(v,w))

dot_prod([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

I am getting the following error: `TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable`

Any help in resolving this issue is greatly appreciated...Thanks!

Comment: Seems OK to me at a glance.

Comment: Seconding @MateenUlhaq, this runs as expected on my machine (python 3.8)

Comment: The code seems to be fine and running with Python 3.7.5 as well. What version of Python are you running?

Comment: Have you redefined `sum` or `zip`?  The posted code works on a clean invocation of Python 3.

Comment: Thanks everybody. It had to with @TomKarzes question. I started a new session and was able to execute without any issue.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to do it manually you can just do that

Firstly you need to install numpy

```
pip3 install numpy # If you use python3
pip install numpy # If you use python2
conda install numpy # If you use anaconda
```

Then Use this code

```
import numpy as np

def dot_prod(x, y):  # X,Y are the vectors
    return np.dot(x, y)
```

To avoid ValueError:

```
def dot_prod(x, y):
    try:
       return np.dot(x, y)
    except ValueError:
       return np.dot(x, np.array(y).T)
```